# CSS-styling on my form doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have this login form, which works and looks just fine in Chrome, IE11 and Edge but when try it out on Firefox, it looks completely different;

My labels are not the same width, so I have to re-adjust them. Also, my submit button doesn't seem to take on styles.

How can I make this work with Firefox as well?

**My HTML:**

```
 <div class="loginheader">تسجيل الدخول</div>

    <div class="loginform">
 <form   action="login.php" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
    <p>
      <label for="loginform">اسم المستخدم</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="login" value="mohammed.nasyia@gmail.com" placeholder="اسم المستخدم" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="loginform">كلمة المرور</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="mohammed.nasyia@gmail.com" placeholder="كلمة المرور" />
    </p>

    <p >
      <input  type="submit"  name="submit" value="تسجيل الدخول" class="button   admin-login-button"/>
    </p>


  </form>

  </div>
     <div class="loginfooter">

   <a href="#"   class="examinee">  تسجيل الدخول كممتحن  </a>



     </div>


    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.login-container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
.loginform {
direction:RTL;
    padding: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
}
.loginheader {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.loginfooter {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.loginheader, .loginfooter {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
label {
    float: rihgt;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.edit-examinee label{
    float: rihgt;
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.loginform label {
    float: rihgt;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    overflow: visible;
    font: bold 16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.admin-login-button {
    margin-right: 350px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.admin-login-button:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.admin-login-button:active {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
}
```

You can also check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nasyia/6p4v9hs6/4/) of the form.

Comment: Just a comment: you have `float: rihgt;` instead of `float: right;` several times in your css

Comment: I get exactly the same layout on firefox (ver 47) as chrome
Try again with all your addons disabled.

Comment: Identically on firefox & chrome for me :-)

Comment: I have looked on both browsers on OSX, and the layout is the exactly the same.

From what you mention though as your problem, it seems that you are noticing the different font rendering methods used by Firefox and Chrome.

I, personally, have never been able to achieve the exact same font rendering between browsers.

Comment: this is how it look in firefox https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2016/08/02/2016-08-022.png

Comment: thank you for mentioning my typo i didn't notice them @wasthishelpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the floats (with a typo), set the margin to left on the `.admin-login-button`. I also added a media query for smaller screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/6p4v9hs6/7/

New CSS here:

```
.login-container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
.loginform {
direction:RTL;
    padding: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
}
.loginheader {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.loginfooter {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.loginheader, .loginfooter {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
label {
    /* float: rihgt; */
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.edit-examinee label{
    /* float: rihgt; */
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.loginform label {
    /* float: rihgt; */
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    overflow: visible;
    font: bold 16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.admin-login-button {
    margin-left: 350px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.admin-login-button:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.admin-login-button:active {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    input[type=text], input[type=password] {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Seems to work in both Safari and Firefox.